# Упрощение загрузки сайта

Tags: jquery, ajax, загрузка, оптимизация-сайтов

Вопрос такой, будет ли страница грузиться быстрее и не сильно ли нагрузить сервер, если загружать страницу с несколькими, одновременными запросами к серверу?
**Перевод:** Разделить страницу на блоки и загружать через ajax в них отдельно контекст.
С одной стороны этот вывод ни чем не лучше обычного, но с другой, если к примеру на странице есть блок, с кучей вывода из базы данных, то пока оно не загрузиться, то другая часть не будет показана, так как грузится все поэтапно.
Из-за этого, если подгружать этот блок через ajax, то следующий блок уже будет загружен, так как он не связан с этапами загрузки.
Может я сказал очевидную вещь, не кидайтесь помидорами. Но для меня это в новинку, заметил, что Facebook работает примерно по такой же схеме. 
Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Вообще принято грузить сначало html, потом стили и за ними скрипты. Сейчсас уже, наверное, не вспомню. Где видел, что вообще лучше всё в одном документе отправлять. Чем меньше запросов, тем лучше. Вот график [SO](http://sitespeed.ru/result/160712_GJ_2K/1/details/#content)

Comment: Вспомнил, вот здесь проверка и рекомендации по улучшению загрузки сайта [Developers Google Pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

Comment: Можно же просто отложенной загрузкой пользоваться? Сейчас уже в браузере нативно можно это делать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Предлагаю вам все же сначала загружать HTML, CSS а в конце сами скрипты, как в комментариях выше.

- Используйте прогрузку скриптов от Google, это не будет кушать ваш трафик на хосторе.
- Используйте Google Pagespeed, как уже сказано в комментариях.
- Оптимизируйте картинки:

  - Используйте к примеру фотошоп, сохраняйте их в 128 или 64-битных цветах, для web, это также скажется на скорости прогрузки страницу.
  - Если картинка по размеру к примеру в 4к, а вам нужно максимум 1080, уменьшите картинку хотя бы в два раза. Для 4к мониторов, лучше её увеличивать искуственно.
  - Либо другой вариант, для каждого разрешения экрана разные картинки, что позволит на мобильных устройствах загружать картинки быстрее.

Answer (score 3):

> будет ли страница грузиться быстрее и не сильно ли нагрузить сервер,
>   если загружать страницу с несколькими, одновременными запросами к
>   серверу?

1. Нет, не будет. Но можно оптимизировать визуализацию.
2. Да, это создаст доп. нагрузку на сервер.

Полезно ознакомиться: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/?hl=ru